# How eliminate selection in ManytoMany form field

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="buyer")
    smokers = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

And have this form:

```
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['smokers', 'price',]
```

I would like to access smokers field and eliminate few options (that user won't be able to select it or even see it in HTML). Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in your form's `__init__()` method like this:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['smokers'].queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(...)  # your filter

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('smokers', 'price',)
```